# get cell +1 based on cell Value?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a container bound Script and a htmlService Sidebar.

The sheet contains 2 columns B, C.
B contains a ID, C contains a item name.
You enter the ID into the html input and submit, if theres a ID matching the one you enter the row gets deleted.
Now i want to use the confirm() method to confirm the deletion like so:
"Are sure that you want to delete "+itemName+" form your Inventory"

My problem is that im struggling to get the to the ID adjacent Item name cell value.

**JS**

```js
var adjacentName = ??????

function showDeleteElectronics() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var deleteElectronicsForm = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('DeleteElectronicsHTML')
  deleteElectronicsForm.itemName = adjacentName;
  var html = deleteElectronicsForm.evaluate();
  html.setTitle("Elektronik Entfernen")
  ui.showSidebar(html);
}


function deleteElectronics(formObject) {
  var electronicsID = formObject.electronicsLocalID 
  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1GSzlzj7nHPIUt-RIJfsPFobtnLbuoXedtJk1x11BdT0");
  var SHEET = SS.getSheetByName("ElektronikBestand");
  var RANGE = SHEET.getDataRange();
  var DELETE_VAL = electronicsID;
  var LOCAL_ID = 1;

  function deleteItem(){
    
    var rangeVals = RANGE.getValues();
    
    //Reverse the 'for' loop.
    for(var i = rangeVals.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
      if(rangeVals[i][LOCAL_ID] === DELETE_VAL){
        
        SHEET.deleteRow(i+1); 
      };
    };
  };

  deleteItem();
}
```

**HTML**

```html
      <div class="sidebarwrapper">
    
          <div class="xbuttonwrapper">
              <button class="xbutton" onclick="google.script.host.close()">
                  <svg class="x" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 212.982 212.982" style="enable-background:new 0 0 212.982 212.982" xml:space="preserve"><path style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd" d="m131.804 106.491 75.936-75.936c6.99-6.99 6.99-18.323 0-25.312-6.99-6.99-18.322-6.99-25.312 0L106.491 81.18 30.554 5.242c-6.99-6.99-18.322-6.99-25.312 0-6.989 6.99-6.989 18.323 0 25.312l75.937 75.936-75.937 75.937c-6.989 6.99-6.989 18.323 0 25.312 6.99 6.99 18.322 6.99 25.312 0l75.937-75.937 75.937 75.937c6.989 6.99 18.322 6.99 25.312 0 6.99-6.99 6.99-18.322 0-25.312l-75.936-75.936z"/><g/><g/><g/><g/><g/><g/><g/><g/><g/><g/><g/><g/><g/><g/><g/></svg>
              </button>
          </div>
    
          <div class="titlewrapper">
              <img class="ctlogotitle" src="https://i.imgur.com/d1VMjvs.png">
              <h1 class="title">Elektronik <br> Entfernen</h1>
          </div>
    
          <div class="divider"></div>
    
          <form class="inputformwrapper" id="removeElectronicsFrom">
              
              <div class="inputblockwrapper">
                  <div class="labelwrapper">
                      <label class="requiredlabel" for="electronicsLocalID">Lokale ID</label>
                  </div>
    
                  <input class="inputfield" 
                      type="text"
                      placeholder="PREF00000001..."
                      minlength="12"
                      maxlength="12"                
                      id="electronicsLocalID"
                      name="electronicsLocalID"                    
                      required>
              </div>
    
              <div class="confirmbuttonwrapper">
                  <input class="confirmbutton" 
                      type="submit" 
                      value="Entfernen"                
                      id="removeElectronics">
              </div>
    
          </form>
    
      </div>

      <script>
            document.querySelector("#removeElectronicsFrom").addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
                let confirmString = "Are you sure that you want to delete " + itemName + "?";
                e.preventDefault();
                if (confirm(confirmString)) {
                  google.script.run.deleteElectronics(this);
                  $('#removeElectronicsFrom').trigger("reset");
                } else {
                  $('#removeElectronicsFrom').trigger("reset");
                }
            });
      </script>
```

| Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- |
| ID | itemName |
| -- | -- |
| MUCH00000001 | Item1 |
| MUCH00000002 | Item2 |
| MUCH00000003 | Item3 |
| MUCH00000004 | Item4 |
| MUCH00000005 | Item5 |
| MUCH00000006 | Item6 |
| MUCH00000007 | Item7 |
| MUCH00000008 | Item8 |
| MUCH00000009 | Item9 |
| MUCH00000010 | Item10 |

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call the function twice. First to get itemname and then to delete:

#### Server side:

```
function getItemName(formObject) {
  const electronicsID = formObject.electronicsLocalID;
  const SHEET = getSheet();
  const RANGE = SHEET.getDataRange();
  const DELETE_VAL = electronicsID;
  const ITEMNAMECOL = 2;
  const LOCAL_ID = 1;
  const rangeVals = RANGE.getValues();
  //Reverse the 'for' loop.
  for (var i = rangeVals.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (rangeVals[i][LOCAL_ID] === DELETE_VAL) {
      return {
        i,
      //id: rangeVals[i][LOCAL_ID],
        itemName: rangeVals[i][ITEMNAMECOL],
      };
    }
  }
  return {i, itemName: "not found"};
}
function getSheet() {
  const SS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(
    '1GSzlzj7nHPIUt-RIJfsPFobtnLbuoXedtJk1x11BdT0'
  );
  const SHEET = SS.getSheetByName('ElektronikBestand');
  return SHEET;
}
function deleteElectronics(i) {
  getSheet().deleteRow(i + 1);
}
```

#### Client side:

```
document.querySelector("#removeElectronicsFrom").addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(({i, itemName}) => {
    const confirmString = "Are you sure that you want to delete " + itemName + "?";
    if (confirm(confirmString)) {
      google.script.run.deleteElectronics(i);
      $('#removeElectronicsFrom').trigger("reset");
    } else {
      $('#removeElectronicsFrom').trigger("reset");
    }
  }).getItemName(this)
});
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'electronicsLocalID' of undefined
    at getItemName(DeleteItem:10:30)
Im getting a TypeErr ... idk how electronicsLocalID is undefined 


Edit: added .getItemName(this) but now i get 

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'i' of 'object null' as it is null.

Comment: @Rookie_Js See if my update changes anything.

Comment: in hindsight i also need to check if column A is empty do you think it i can just edit the question or would it make more sense to open a new thread?

Comment: @Rookie_Js New thread please. Changing the goal post after a answer is written is frowned upon.